# Average of the maximum matrix element over the Haar measure

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, unitary-representations, haar-measure

Let $U$ be a $d\times d$ unitary matrix, and $U_{i,j}$ be its matrix elements. I am interested in the following quantity
$$\int dU \max_j |U_{1,j}|^2 \ , $$
where $dU$ is the uniform Haar measure over ${\rm SU}(d)$.

Please let me know if you have any idea for calculating this integral for general $d$.

Comment: Your title asks for the maximum matrix element (out of, presumably, all of them), but your integral only selects the maximum element in the first row.  Which do you mean?

Comment: I believe I've read that the joint distribution of the $|U_{1,j}|^2$ is the uniform distribution on the standard $d$-simplex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the question as stated (maximum of row elements) has been solved in [Extreme statistics of complex random and quantum chaotic states](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0176), see also this [MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298776/11260):

$$\int dU \max_j |U_{1,j}|^2 =\frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{j}.$$

For large $d$ this tends to $(1/d)\log d$. The complete probability distribution of the row-maximum is known.

---

The maximum of *all* matrix elements is more difficult and only large-$d$ asymptotics has a closed-form expression, see [Maxima of entries of Haar distributed matrices](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00440-004-0376-5) (alternative
[link](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~jiang040/papers/haar1.pdf)).

If $W_d$ is the maximum matrix element in absolute value of a Haar-distributed $d\times d$ unitary matrix, then $W_d^2\rightarrow (2/d)\log d$ in probability for $d\rightarrow\infty$, so twice as large as for the row-maximum.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$Any linear isometry of $\C^d$ is a unitary transformation. Therefore, the distribution of the random vector $V:=(X_1,Y_1,\dots,X_d,Y_d)$ is uniform on the unit sphere in $\R^{2d}$, where $X_j:=\Re U_{1,j}$ and $Y_j:=\Im U_{1,j}$. So, $V$ equals $W:=(W_1,\dots,W_{2d})$ in distribution, where 
$$W_j:=\frac{Z_j}{\sqrt{Z_1^2+\dots+Z_{2d}^2}}
$$ 
and $Z_1,\dots,Z_{2d}$ are iid standard normal random variables (r.v.'s). 
So, the random vector $(|U_{1,1}|^2 ,\dots,|U_{1,d}|^2)$ equals 
$R:=(R_1,\dots,R_d)$ in distribution, where 
$$R_j:=\frac{T_j}{T_1+\dots+T_d}
$$ 
and $T_k:=Z_{2k-1}^2+Z_{2k}^2$, so that $T_1,\dots,T_d$ are iid standard exponential r.v.'s. So, $\max_j|U_{1,j}|^2$ equals $\max_j R_j$ in distribution. The distribution and, in particular, the expectation of $\max_j R_j$ were found a long time ago; see e.g. 
[Irwin (1955)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2342709?seq=1) and historical references therein going 
back to as far as 1897. In particular, according to [formula (15) in Cochran's paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1941.tb02271.x), 
$$E\max_j|U_{1,j}|^2=E\max_j R_j=\frac1d\,\Big(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1d\Big). 
$$